# How to set up a reverse proxy for Apache on Business-Objects BI 4.1?

Tags: apache, server, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf, business-objects

I need to know exactly what to add in the **httpd.conf** file in order to set up a reverse proxy for Apache on these two links :

```
http://localhost:8080/BOE

http://localhost:8080/AdminTools
```

I found some information on this page : http://solveissue.com/note?id=1676146

```
ProxyPass /BI4/BOE http://localhost:8080/BOE

ProxyPassReverseCookiePath //BI4/BOE

ProxyPass /BI4/AdminTools http://localhost:8080/AdminTools

ProxyPassReverseCookiePath //BI4/AdminTools
```

But not enough to make it work. I always get this error when starting Apache :

```
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath takes two or three arguments, Path rewrite rule for proxying cookies
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a space.  It should be:

```
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath    /    /BI4/BOE
```

(extra spaces added for clarification)

Comment: Can you please explain what is **BI4** in this example, I am kinda new to this.

Comment: /BI4 is the root virtual directory.  What you are trying to do is cause a call to `http://server/BI4/BOE` to be remapped as `http://server:8080/BOE`.

Comment: One more question please : how do i know if the reverse proxy is working fine ?

Comment: Go to `http://server/BI4/BOE` and see what happens :)  If you see a logon screen for BO, that's a good sign that it works.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36797489/how-to-download-so-files-for-apache