# How to download .SO files for Apache?

Tags: apache, proxy, server, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf

My Apache2/modules folder is missing the following files :

- **mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so**
- **mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so**

I searched everywhere on the internet but it was in vain. Any idea how can I get them ?

I am working on Windows Server 2008.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two files are in **Apache 2.4**, while I am using **Apache 2.2**. Problem solved.